# ASP.NET MVC5: WCF call locks thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Task: start long-running WCF method and then return JSON about successful start.
I've tried Task.Run (with both direct and async call) and HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem and on WCF-side we detect method starting, all is OK, but on MVC side the action runs much longer that needed (few minutes, as example) just like the direct call of service.

So now the code like this

```
public virtual JsonResult RunSomeTask(string data)
{
  Task.Run(() => ourService.LongRunningOne());
//or
  Task.Run(() => ourService.LongRunningOneAsync());
//or
  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((ct) => ourService.LongRunningOne());
//or
  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((ct) => {
    ourService.LongRunningOneAsync();
  });

  return Json(new{message = "started"});
}
```

and it works like just awaits ending of the service call.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This [blog entry](http://anthonygiretti.com/2014/05/18/exploring-queuebackgroundworkitem-in-asp-net-and-framework-4-5-2) has great examples on how to use _HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem_ (this would be your preferred choice). Start with a simple _Thread.Sleep_ first (as showing in the examples), once you got this working, try with your own action

Comment: I need to run my task in separate thread, and after call (without waiting to end) controller action must return result and free thread back to pool.

Comment: You probably have a conceptional issue then. Either you do a sort of "Fire And Forget", then you will not receive any useful result, because when the Request ends, the Action is not finished yet, and no one knows if it will finish or when. Or you need to await the result, in this case, the request will be kept open and running, but might run into a timeout etc. What you might want it to introduce something like [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). What is your purpose?

Comment: «Fire And Forget» — this one.

Comment: Looks like the source of problems is an AutoFac. Manually created service client works OK.

Comment: So at this stage, this is a different topic, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it happened due to use of **AutoFac**, in which services configured as `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`, so in places where problems occurs (when calling service methods in `Task.Run()`, QueueBackgroundWorkItem etc) we just manually creating new service clients (e.g. `OurDataServiceClient`) and then it all works.